# Why is HttpStatusCodeException.getResponseBodyAsString() empty when called after restTemplate.exchange with httpMethod.POST

Tags: java, spring

I just ran into that issue and can't get why this happens.

client-snippet:

```
try {
    ResponseEntity<Credentials> response = this.restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity,
                    Credentials.class);
    this.userCredentials = response.getBody();
    return this.userCredentials;
} catch (HttpStatusCodeException hsce) {
    logger.error("loginUser failed with code " + hsce.getMessage());
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TransmissionFailureException tfe = new TransmissionFailureException();
    try {
    if (hsce.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED) {
        logger.warn(" HIER " + hsce.getMessage());
        throw (CredentialsIncorrectException) mapper.readValue(hsce.getResponseBodyAsString(), CredentialsIncorrectException.class);
...
```

When I set HttpMethod to GET (of course on server side too) hsce.getResponseBodyAsString() returns the JSON representation of my error as String as it is supposed to and Parsing/Mapping works as expected.

The weird thing the exact same Request executed whith SoapUI carries the Exception in the body as expected on POST and GET.

Do I get something wrong here or is that some kind of bug?

Any help will be appreciated.

Kind regards

Edit:
Json Body shown by Soap UI using GET:

```
{
"cause": null,
"stackTrace":    [
...
],
"localizedMessage": "No user found with given username...",
"message": "No user found with given username...",
"suppressed": []
}
```

Json Body shown by Soap UI using POST:

```
{
"cause": null,
"stackTrace":    [
        ...
],
"localizedMessage": "No user found with given username...",
"message": "No user found with given username...",
"suppressed": []
}
```

StackTrace is too long, sorry...

Comment: add both responses by GET and POST request executed by SoapUI

Comment: added both GET and POST JSON responses

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I get it why it happens. As i can see from the documentation

> "Note: by default the RestTemplate relies on standard JDK facilities to establish HTTP connections. You can switch to use a different HTTP library such as Apache HttpComponents, Netty, and OkHttp through the HttpAccessor.setRequestFactory(org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory) property."

and see their [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html) and the warning:

> Note that the java.net implementation for HTTP requests may raise an
>   exception when accessing the status of a response that represents an
>   error (e.g. 401). If this is an issue, switch to
>   HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory instead.

so `java.net` impl raise an exception if status code is 401 (unauthorized).

to get the response body as string just change the request factory to your `RestTemplate`.

```
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
```

or

```
    template.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
```

to use apache http components. See links [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9367) and  [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9999)

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply.
I tried
`this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  this.restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());`

result is an error that says: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/HttpClient

I imported org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;

Comment: brilliant... it is working now.
(I forgot to tell maven to get the package (org.apache.httpcomponents) 
thx man that helped!

Comment: Tried that today, still getting an empty body for a 401 request, tried spring 3.2 and 4.3 same result